# JQuery Parent() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add a class of active to the `ul` and this following code does do that, but is there a better way of finding the `ul` without using 3 `parent()` selectors?

```
$('.header ul li img').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$.closest() traverses up the tree looking for a selector
[docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest( 'ul' );
```

Comment: fantastic answer, Never used closest() before, will do this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @CecilTheodore jQuery has a *lot* of methods to keep track of. In my experience, the best way to learn jQuery well is to skim the entire online API again every couple of weeks.

Comment: yeh its getting to that stage now i think! ha.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.header ul li img').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

Will find the first parent which is an `ul` up in the DOM tree.

```
$('.header ul li img').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

Will find all `ul`s up the DOM tree