# jQuery selector for .parent().parent()

Tags: jquery-selectors

Given a series of a form's Label and Input elements like:

```
<div class="labelEditwrap">
    <div class="editor-label">
       <label for="Address">Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" id="Address" name="Address" type="text" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Address"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select the outer most div when the textbox gets focus so I can highlight both label and input:

```
$("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("curFocus")
});
```

I've tried a few combinations including:

```
$(this).parent().parent() // seems the most obvious
$(this).parent().parents("div:first")
```

Another question here asking about .parent().parent() was solved by finding a syntax error unrelated to the selector. However, in this case, I can see my hightlighter class if I go up only one parent level (only highlights the editor's div) and also if I climb 3 levels (highlights the container holding the full form).

thx

OK....its not the selector. All the suggested alternates (and the original) are correctly 'selecting' the outside wrapper div. The problem was the CSS and how Floats are being applied to the Label and Editor divs. This CSS will produce correct highlighting and also let the label/editor fields align themselves correctly. [whew]

Up to you guys the best way to close/edit/retitle the question in hopes of helping other avoid my 4 hour toubleshooting ordeal.

-highly appreciate the time taken-

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Parent() selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996157/jquery-parent-selector)

Comment: OK....its not the selector. All the suggested alternates (and my original) are correctly 'selecting' the outside wrapper div. The problem is how Floats are being applied to the Label and Editor divs:

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solutions:-

```
$('.text-box').live('focus', function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().css('border', '1px solid red');
});

$('.text-box').live('blur', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().css('border', 'none');
});
```

or

```
$('.text-box').bind('focus', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().css('border', '1px solid red');
});

$('.text-box').bind('blur', function(){
 $(this).parent().parent().css('border', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you suggested should work correctly
    $(this).parent().parent();
I think the issue here is that your event is being bound before there is an object to bind it to.  Have you bound your function on document ready? 
Something like:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").focus(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("curFocus")
    });
});
```

Otherwise using 'live' or 'on' to bind the event will work dynamically.
so like:

```
$('input').live('focus', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("curFocus");
});
```